# Solder joints on copper producing a voltage when twisted or bent

Tags: voltage, soldering

I was thinking a solder joint on a magnetic copper wire (AWG 18) was bad, because pressing against the joint was lowering the measured resistance from 1.5 ohm to 1.2-1.1 ohm.

However, I then pressed it harder and it fell to 0 ohm. My multimeter doesn't measure 0 ohm even in a short on the leads, so I knew something was off.

I changed to DC voltage scale and it measured voltages up to some 50 mV when twisting either side of the joints.

What effect is producing this voltage?

I thought it could be heating and then producing a voltage due to Seebeck effect, but it's happening way too fast and I think those voltages are too high to be Seebeck from the little heating this bending is causing.

Comment: "magnetic copper wire"? Copper is not magnetic. Are you referring to "magnet wire" (which is not itself actually "magnetic")?

Comment: Tip: I think you meant "copper magnet-wire". Copper wire isn't magnetic. "Snap!"

Comment: Are you pressing it with your finger? It could be the Seebeck effect from your finger heat

Comment: Can we see a picture of this connection?  It could be "dirty" or wrong solder/flux was used.  A picture is worth a thousand words...

Comment: PLEASE include information from your comments into your question. People may vote ti close if you provide too little details.

Answer (score 2):

If the joint is opening up it's not hard to get momentary readings of that general magnitude from capacitive pickup of AC signals floating around the room (assuming you have your hands on the probes).

Comment: The joint is certainly not opening however, it's a quite large joint and the solder isn't breaking.

Plus, I did not touch any part of the circuit with my hands, the entire joint was insulated with thermal spaghetti.

And, touching it merely induces no signal, only bending or pressing strongly. The stronger the larger the signal induced.

And it's a DC signal apparently, not AC.

Answer (score 1):

Normally oxidation can raise the resistance to the 1-ohm point range and reduce with more force and area contact to break thru the lead oxide.  I suspect this is the result of your actions.

Sharp needle tips may improve these results.  There are many weaknesses on contact resistance readings in inexpensive DMM's. Sometimes one has to remove one probe to test the other alone in a short circuit null calibration test. This isolates the result to one probe or the other where the contact resistance fault may be in the cable, connector or the socket.

Otherwise I would first suspect the solder surface oxide for a DMM using 0.1 mA to 1mA for this R test using constant current.

Twisting the cables can change the loop induction of stray common-mode hum at say Vcm=50V/m e-fields and possibly be converted to a differential voltage of 50 mV or 1000:1 conversion with help from the diode rectification and protection in meters.

Comment: I'm not making electrical contact with any part of the circuit, nor is the probe touching the soldered joint either.

The probes were wound with the tips of two insulated cables, these cables were soldered to a magnetic wire coil. 

The joints are insulated by thermal spaghetti.

And by twist I didn't mean changing the geometry of the coil nor moving the wire, I meant twisting about the axis parallel to the wire itself, or pressing the wire and causing it to lightly bend.

The wire doesn't move even 1 mm when I press it, the area of the loop is unchanged.

Comment: TY for the details. That is important.  The number of twists per m  increases L very slightly and maybe coupling capacitance C greatly if that is a much tighter gap with very thin enamel insulation.  Thus lowering impedance to stray hum.  Still it is hard to estimate but the magnet wire insulation might < 1um so a 1mm reduction if in air gap greatly increases wire C and reduces Z towards << 100 ohms while inductance of each wire cancels improving CMRR. Again a very large CM voltage but very low differential rectified DC voltage

Comment: But the wire isn't moving closer to other loops of the same coil, however. Let me be more clear: This is the main winding of a 2-pole induction motor, and this solder joint in question is in one of the extremities, not over the main winding itself but rather passing over the auxiliary winding (which wasn't connected to anything either).

Pressing it causes a negligible movement, because the windings are very tight.